# How to set the currency of a GL transaction in code

Tags: acumatica

I'm creating transactions in code using graph objects for GLTran, and I'd like to be able to set/change the currency as you would on the screen.  I only have access to the 'CuryInfoID' field - which isn't a currency.  The control on the screen is a bit cryptic, as it's not a field in the Batch DAC - it seems to be its own control.

Is there a way in C# code, using the graph object, to set the currency ID to something like 'USD', or 'GBP' as you can in the control on the screen?

What's the best way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to set the `Batch` DAC (GLTran's parent header record).

```
batch.CuryID = "USD"
```

Set this before inserting your `GLTran` lines. Do not worry about setting `CuryInfoID` as this should be set for you after setting `CuryID` and saving.

Comment: Jeez - thanks, Brendan.  I don't know why I thought to change that at the tran level.  So simple.

Comment: No worries. I think it the same logic across Acumatica. Sales Orders for example you would set CuryID in the header and all lines by default get the correct set of CuryInfoID